# Why my properties are not set within my js unit test?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am new to Unit Testing with Javascript.
I have the following model:

```
export class CartItem {
  item: Item;

  someVariableWhichIsNotImportant = {};

  varA = 12;
  constructor(cfg: Partial<CartItem> = {}) {
    if (!cfg.item) {
      throw new Error('Item is missing');
    }
    //...some other error conditions
    this.item = cfg.item;
    //....some other variables
  }
}
```

Then, my very simple, yet broken unit tests as follows:

```
import { Item } from './item.model';
import { CartItem } from './cart-item.model';

describe('something to describe', () => {
  let a;
  const titel = "blah blah";
  const ITEM_1 = new Item();
  ITEM_1.title = title1 

  const CART_ITEM = new CartItem();
  CART_ITEM.item = ITEM_1;

  it('should have a start date of xxx', () => {
    expect(ITEM_1.tile).toBe(title1);
  });

});
```

When I run the test I have `Error: Item is missing`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `new CartItem()` would cause that error because there's no cfg provided `new CartItem({ item: ITEM_1 })` would probably work

Comment: You need to inject the dependencies to  `new CartItem();` The constructor for CartItem expects some values to create instance of class.

Comment: `const titel` is a typo, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the dependencies to `new CartItem()`; 
The constructor for `CartItem` in your code expects : `cfg: Partial<CartItem>` to create instance of class.

Add the mocked `cfg` to your `CART_ITEM` Ex:

```
const CART_ITEM = new CartItem(mockedCfg);
```

try to pass these values at the time of initialization and it should work.